# iPad behaves like it is low on RAM

Tags: ipad, memory

My iPAD Air (2021) started to behave as if it has low RAM, all apps are reloading after just couple of seconds. If I switch from Youtube app to Safari after some seconds Youtube app will reload completely. This happens with all the apps. It has around 9 gigs of free space. IOS 15.4.1

I wonder before erasing it if somebody has any info how this should be fixed (tried to exit all apps and restarted couple if times.)

Comment: Free space is not RAM. iOS devices only have so much RAM, so some swapping is to be expected. Also because iOS is not designed as a multitasking OS from the POV of user apps, then it's normal for an app to be 'put to sleep' completely. (Apologies for that mental image... ;-) It would help if you edit your answer to include the model number of your iPad, then the amount of RAM it has can be known.

Comment: Before erasing, try updating to 15.7.

Comment: See also https://support.apple.com/guide/ipad/force-restart-ipad-ipad9955c007/ipados

Comment: @AndyGriffiths thank you for your reply. I know that ram is not a storage. I know how iOS treating “closed” apps as well. In my case it is behave as if after youtube app for example i run something that is big on ram so the system would purge youtube from memory as expected. The only difference between expected behavior  and my case is that iOS purge any app almost immediately and this is clearly not expected behavior..

Comment: @lhf thank you very much, yeah i tried to force restart just wondered maybe something else is an option as well, really don’t want to wipe everything will take forever to reupload everything from iCloud

Answer (score 0):

For somebody in same situation - only wipe and iOS reinstall fixed the issue. iPad was not able to update as well.